# Tricky Apache Rewrite Push State + Adding WWW

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, single-page-application, httpd.conf, pushstate

What I'm trying to achieve is adding (forcing) WWW in front of my push state URLs when it is not present.

I tried to get familiar with rewrites, and looked around for possible solutions. Also tried many variations on my local machine. Somehow I just don't get it right.

Here is what I have, which is working (inside my httpd.conf file)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !emails/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !icons/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !src-svg/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !svg/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !css/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tmpl/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !js/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !crawl/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !config/*
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried removing the last [L] and add different variations of these lines, or writing the rule in one single line, but to no avail.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

So the trick would be to add WWW and point the browser silently to the index.php file (which represents my single page application using push state). The directory names listed in the first code block should be excluded from the index.php rule and may not receive the WWW.

Thanks for any input!

**EDIT**

I have the following now, which seems to work so far. It seems some flags were at fault. Is this a valid approach?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !emails/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !icons/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !src-svg/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !svg/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !css/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tmpl/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !js/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !crawl/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !config/*
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me now

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !emails/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !icons/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !src-svg/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !svg/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !css/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tmpl/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !js/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !crawl/*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !config/*
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```